# Code is not cyclic for any q

Tags: coding-theory, information-theory

I have code $C$ over $F_p$ with generator matrix which looks like

$G = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 &0& 0& 1& 0& 1& 1 &1\\
1& 0 &0& 0 &1 &0 &1& 1\\
1& 1& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0& 1\\
1 &1& 1& 0 &0 &0& 1 &0\end{pmatrix}$

I need to show that this code is not cyclic for any $p$.

I constructed vector which looks like 
$$(c_2+c_3+c_4, c_3+c_4, c_4, c_1, c_2, c_1+c_3, c_1+c_2+c_4, c_1+c_2+c_3)$$ and its shifts but it didn't help me a lot.

Does somebody have any ideas how it can be proven?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong.. Cyclic code means that the vectorial space of the code is a cyclic group? If that's it, then it's easy

Comment: No, to be cyclic code must satisfy:
1) It is linear code
2) Any of cyclic shifts of codewords is again codeword of this code.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the word $(3,2,1,1,1,2,3,3)$ in $C$, which is the sum of the four rows.
Now consider the cyclically shifted word $(3,3,3,2,1,1,1,2)$. If the code would be cyclic, this must 
be again of the form $(c_2+c_3+c_4, c_3+c_4, c_4, \ldots ,c_1+c_2+c_3)$. Hence we would obtain 
\begin{align*}
c_2+c_3+c_4 & =3 \\
c_3+c_4 & = 3 \\
c_4 & = 3
\end{align*}
so that $c_2=c_3=0$, $c_4=3$. Furthermore $c_1=2$. But then it follows that $(3,3,3,2,1,1,1,2)=(3,3,3,2,0,2,5,2)$, a contradiction in any field, because of $0\neq 1$.

Comment: Why that word is in C?

Comment: Which word do you mean ?

Comment: It seems like you lost that $c_i \in F_q$ and

\begin{align*}
c_2+c_3+c_4 & =3 \mod{q} \\
c_3+c_4 & = 3 \mod{q} \\
c_4 & = 3 \mod{q}
\end{align*}

Such system of equations isn't that obvious for me for any q.

Comment: It is easy to solve in $\mathbb{F}_q$. Note that we obtain $0\equiv 1 \mod q$ with which is false for every prime power $q$.

Answer (score 1):

$C$ must contain every cyclic shift of its codewords. Consider the cyclic shift of the last row of $G$, $x = \left( {01110001} \right)$. If $C$ is a cyclic code, $x$ must be a linear combination of the rows of $G$, i.e.

${x^T} = a\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0\\
0\\
0\\
1\\
0\\
1\\
1\\
1
\end{array}} \right) + b\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
1\\
0\\
1\\
1
\end{array}} \right) + c\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1\\
1\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
1\\
0\\
1
\end{array}} \right) + d\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1\\
1\\
1\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
1\\
0
\end{array}} \right)$
for some $a,b,c,d \in {F_p}$.

Then, it is not hard to see that 
$b + c + d = 0\left( p \right)$ and $c + d = 1\left( p \right)$ from the sum of first and second components of the rows, respectively. From the fifth components, $b=0$. So, 
$c + d = 1\left( p \right)$ and $c + d = 0\left( p \right)$. This is not possible for all prime $p$.

Answer (score 0):

A base for your code is a base for $\ker G$. So the code has dimension 4, and a base is
$$
v_1=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}
\quad v_2=\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}
\quad v_3=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}
\quad v_4=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}
$$

The code was cyclic if and only if the base, shifted by one, is still a base of the code, but

$$
v_2=\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}
\quad v_3=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}
\quad v_4=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}
\quad v_1=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}
$$ 
Is a base, so **it is cyclic** for every p

Comment: Could you please point me to proof of this fact "The code was cyclic if and only if the base, shifted by one, is still a base of the code"? I have never heard about such statement.

Comment: No, cyclic means that also the cyclic permutations of all linear combinations (not only the base vectors) are again in $C$. And this is not the case.

Comment: If a base generate a code, his shift by one generate the code shifted by one. For example, if $v=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+...$, then $v'=a_1v'_1+...$ is his shifted, and if the base generate the same space, you have all the permutations of $v$ by induction..

Comment: Perhaps I am wrong, but what is with the word $(3,2,1,1,1,2,3,3)$, which is in $C$ ? Not all cyclic shifts here are again in $C$. Perhaps you mean that $C$ is *equivalent* to a cyclic code.

Comment: Found the bug: my definition of code is the kernel of the matrix, not the image. My bad